# Eclipse Birt Reports, Creating report from SQL database, (user key?)

Tags: eclipse, sqlite, birt

I'm fairly new to using the Birt Report Designer and need to figure out how to generate a report from a SQLite database. I have suceeded in getting it to connect to the DB but am now unsure how to generate a report and the tutorials that I have found aren't of much help so far.

I have a template that was given to me by my employer that has a few fields, I'm wondering if these fieldnames (in the template) are supposed to match field names in the DB.

Also, when I go to Run->View Report-> As PDF I am unsure what I am supposed to enter for the field "User Key", does this correspond to a table name in the DB or something along these lines?

As of now, I have tried entering a table name but just a blank report is generated.

If anyone can point me to a good resource or help with this I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two books i could really advice:

1. BIRT - A Field Guide to Reporting
2. Integrating and Extending BIRT

and the Eclipse Help containing BIRT documentation.

I suppose the User Key could be report parameter (listed in Data Explorer window), which is passed to Data Set to select appropriate data. If I'm guessing right, check within a Data Set editor ("Parameters" tab and "Query" tab) where the User Key parameter goes in - probably to one of the table field in a `WHERE` clause. Parameters in a query are represented by question marks: `SELECT * FROM fooTable WHERE barColumn = ?`. Hope tracking this would lead to find out, what to enter to the parameter.

Additionally, ensure if your Data Set(s) is(are) connected correctly to your SQLite Data Source ("Data Source" tab in a Data Set editor).

Answer (score 0):

Being as new as you are to BIRT, I would suggest building a couple of reports with the sample DB (Classic Models).  There are many, many samples out there for you to use as a guide.  Additionally, most tutorials will use the Classic Models data so you can follow right along.  After you create a couple of practice reports (this should not take more than 30-45 minutes) the template you have been given will likely make A LOT more sense and allow you to make progress almost immediately.

If you are looking for a nice collection of tutorials and samples, be sure to check out [Birt Exchange](http://www.birt-exchange.org/) for Dev Share (samples) & tutorials.

As for the "User Key" this is almost certainly a report-level parameter used to filter the data set (as the previous answer points out).

Good Luck!